# "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) " What does this mean?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I've seen this message several times whenever someone has a problem installing, upgrading or removing some piece of software, but I wonder, **what does it mean**, and more importantly, is possible to solve it?

```
(Reading database ... 81657 files and directories currently installed.)
 Removing mongodb-10gen ...
 arg: remove
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
 dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--remove):
  subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
 dpkg: error while cleaning up:
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  mongodb-10gen
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

*(the above is just an example, not my actual problem)*

Comment: If you tried `apt-get install (something)` and you got this error message like I did, the solution for me was `apt-get upgrade (something)`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That message is generic. It just means that the `dpkg` instance called by `apt`/`apt-get` failed for some reason. It doesn't explain why, how, or give hints how to solve it. As a diagnostic message, it is not useful.

You need to read the lines before the message (sometimes quite a number of them) to find the real error that prevents you from completing the installation.

### Yeah, but how do I solve it?

There is no single way to solve it. There are so many reasons why this can happen that it's futile to attempt to list them all in a single post. Each and every circumstance is almost unique to that package/environment.

But, there's redemption. The fact that you see this message means that probably there is more relevant information in the lines before the message. For illustrative purposes I will use a example:

```
(Reading database ... 81657 files and directories currently installed.)
 Removing mongodb-10gen ...
 arg: remove
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
 dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--remove):
  subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
 invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.
 dpkg: error while cleaning up:
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  mongodb-10gen
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now, to find the problem, you need to read backwards:

- `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` doesn't tell me anything useful. So moving on.
- `Errors were encountered while processing: mongodb-10gen` just tells me what package have problems. Is useful but not enough.
- `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100`: this tells me that the script that failed was the `postinst`, the one executed in post-installation. This will come handy in some situations, but not in this one.
- `dpkg: error while cleaning up:` nothing useful here.
- `invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/mongodb not found.` BINGO! This tells us that `invoke-rc.d`, a binary that controls the init script in most Debian-like system, failed. It failed because it couldn't find the `/etc/init.d/mongodb` script. This is bad. We need to create it or copy from somewhere else so it starts working again. Reinstalling the package is also normally an option for `file not found` errors.

  In this case, reporting a bug is not necessary because is probable that we were the ones that removed the script, but if you are completely sure you didn't touch the file (a `debsums -sla` should confirm it) then report a bug.

So, what exactly do you need to get help? Ideally, the complete output of the problem. It's also helpful to include the output of `sudo dpkg -C` and `sudo apt-get check`, and the output of `apt-cache policy package1 package2...` where "package1 package2 ..." includes all the packages with problems.

Comment: as a diagnostic message it IS helpful if you read the entire error (Errors were encountered while processing: mongodb-10gen) that's why it is listed as E and not Error

Comment: @mchid but what caused the error? It doesn't give you the sightless clue.

Comment: @mchid yes, how can I figure out that if I just read `Errors were encountered while processing: mongodb-10gen`? As it is, to solve the problem, that line is *worthless*.

Comment: My bad I thought you were just looking for how to fix the problem ("is it possible to solve it") I guess I took that out of context.

Comment: BTW, run `sudo touch /etc/init.d/mongodb` and then run `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen` to fix the problem. I tested this and as long as the file exists (/etc/init.d/mongodb) dpkg will proceed even if the file is empty which is what touch does (creates an empty file).

Comment: @mchid I've said already many times **is an example**