# "EOFError: EOF read where object expected" while installing python-rpi.gpio

Tags: raspbian, dpkg

On a clean install of Raspbian Jessie (Raspberry pi 2) an error occurs during the first attempt for upgrade:

```
Preparing to unpack .../python-rpi.gpio_0.6.1-1_armhf.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 31, in <module>
    from debpython import files as dpf
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 31, in <module>
    from debpython import files as dpf
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rpi.gpio_0.6.1-1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 37, in <module>
    from debpython import files as dpf
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../python3-rpi.gpio_0.6.1-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python3-rpi.gpio (0.6.1-1) over (0.6.0a3-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../raspi-config_20160108_all.deb ...
Unpacking raspi-config (20160108) over (20151117) ...
Preparing to unpack .../rc-gui_0.4-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking rc-gui (0.4-1) over (0.3-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../sudo_1.8.10p3-1+deb8u3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking sudo (1.8.10p3-1+deb8u3) over (1.8.10p3-1+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../sonic-pi_1%3a2.9.0-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking sonic-pi (1:2.9.0-1) over (1:2.7.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rpi.gpio_0.6.1-1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139586/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-what-does-this-mean) it seems the problem lies in  python-rpi.gpio. The question how to overcome it. Most importantly because no other installs are now possible.

Common suggestions like `apt-get clean` or `dpkg --configure -a` unfortunately do not help.

```
ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.1.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.
```

What can be done besides downgrading to Raspbian Wheezy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual cause was a faulty SD card with incorrectly implemented delete functionality, where deleting during upgrade changed other files as well.

Answer (score -1):

get `sonic-pi` manually and retry ....

```
wget http://sonic-pi.net/files/releases/v2.9.0/Sonic-Pi-for-RPi-Jessie-v2.9.0.tgz
tar -xvzf Sonic-Pi-for-RPi-Jessie-v2.9.0.tgz
```